# How to declare a global variable in ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-variables

I've began working with asp.net mvc very recently and I've ran into a problem.
I've got an aspx page which renders a few ascx pages. What I'd like to do is declare a global var at the aspx page so it is visible to all its childs. I tried `<% var i = 0; %>` but it wasn't visible at the child pages.

What could I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

variables from a aspx page are not shared with the partial views.
The view is just a representation of a piece of data. You have to pass the data as a Model to each view you want to render, whether it's a plain View or a PartialView.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", Model, ViewDataDictionnary) %>
```

If you want to pass a variable to a partial view, I would strongly recommend you to add this parameter to the model of the partial view, rather that to pass it additionally via the ViewDataDictionnary.

Comment: Does this apply to two views inheriting from a shared view? If I were to declare and use a variable in the shared view, would I be able to override it in the inheriting views to change the output?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the case related to this question, but the view is just a class that renders html. But the variable will still not be shared across different calls to RenderPartial since that would create different instance of the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the ViewData and then pass the ViewData to the ascx with

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", Model, ViewData) %>
```

see [msdn on RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(VS.90).aspx)

So in your aspx page you'd do something like

```
<% ViewData["i"] = 0; %>
```

And in your userControl you'd just retrive it and use it as you want

```
<% int i = (int)ViewData["i"] %>
```

Another way would be to use RenderAction eand pass it as a parameter... so we'd need to know how you display your ascx.

see [msdn on RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx)