# Global Variables in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, global-variables

I'm currently building an ASP.Net MVC 4 SAAS application (C#) and am stuck on designing the plans. I mean if a customer picks `Plan A` they should have access to some things and if they pick `Plan B` they get access to others and so on.

The Part that I'm stuck on is be best practice of sharing the account's plan with all of the actions. I realize having global variables are bad practice and all but I really don't want to take round trips to the DB to get the plan on every action.

What I'm thinking of doing is something like [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118750/1244328) where they just declare a static model and set it at some point and access it later on. In your opinion, is this the best way of doing this? is there a better way?

Comment: **but I really don't want to take round trips to the DB to get the plan on every action** Below approach is going to make db call on each action. Correct ?

Comment: @PKKG: there is a check to ensure that we load only once.

Comment: @Khanh : That is the memory of Interface not the memory of data. right ? So, each request for action will go to db

Comment: @PKKG: there is only 1 instance of IConfigService interface if we configure this instance as singleton in our IoC (our IoC holds a reference to it) and reuse it throughout the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think best practice is you should include an IoC in your project and inject a configuration object to your controller.

Example code of a controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller
 {
     private IConfigService _configService;

     //inject your configuration object here.
     public YourController(IConfigService configService){
           // A guard clause to ensure we have a config object or there is something wrong
           if (configService == null){
               throw new ArgumentNullException("configService");
           }
           _configService = configService;
     }
 }
```

You could configure your IoC to specify singleton scope for this configuration object. In case you need to apply this pattern to all your controllers, you could create a base controller class to reuse code.

Your IConfigService

```
public interface IConfigService
{
    string ConfiguredPlan{ get; }
}
```

Your ConfigService:

```
public class ConfigService : IConfigService
{
    private string _ConfiguredPlan = null;

    public string ConfiguredPlan
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ConfiguredPlan == null){
                    //load configured plan from DB
            }
            return _ConfiguredPlan;
        }
    }
}
```

- This class is easily extended to include more configurations like connection String, Default timeout,...
- We're passing in an interface to our controller class, it's easy for us to mock this object during unit testing.

Comment: Wow, I really like this solution. I will try to implement it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: me too :) I'm really a newbee when it comes to DI. I really have to start thinking that way

Comment: You are saying IOC, but this is `Dependency Injections`? You are injecting the `Interface`(dependency) in `Constructor`.

Comment: @PKKG: you should know the differences between these terms. Dependency Injection is a set of software design principles and patterns
that enable us to develop loosely coupled code. IoC or DI container is a software library that provides DI functionality. Hope it's clear. Have a nice day.

Comment: So internally, Inversion of Control does Singleton Pattern Class Implementation ?

Comment: @PKKG: no, it's much more than that. We can do more with IoC. I think you could take a look on some documentations to get more information

Comment: @PKKG: it's about using an IoC to achieve DI. Remember that DI is just a concept, not an actual implementation.

Comment: @PKKG: NInject, Castle Windsor, Unity,.. are all examples of IoC (they are software libraries that provide DI functionality)

Comment: Will you like to share the documentation that support your last comment ?

Comment: @PKKG: I read all that information from this book: http://books.google.com.vn/books/about/Dependency_Injection_in_NET.html?id=lnOqcQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: No need to go through all this complex logics. Just use the singleton pattern on a class(with whatever you want in it) and use it as a 'Global thing'