# how to pass values from one view to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

am very new to ASP.NET USING MVC Controllers...so here is my scenario.Am developing an Online Admission system where students come and fill in their required records to be processed for admission.I have different classes that holds specific information about the student.My student class is:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FIRSTNAME { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LASTNAME { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class called Enrollments where the user Enters all the courses as well as the Grade

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
public enum Grade
{
    A,B,C,D,E,F
}
}
```

AND different more classes.I HAVE A CONTROLLER called Registration, where i will create the views for each Classes.

SO IN my first View which takes all the student Details,after the Record has been saved.
when the user Clicks next,i want to pass the ID number of the student class to my next view which is the Enrollment View and save the records along with the ID number of the student class which is acting as a foreign key in the enrollment class and database.

Have been trying so hard 2 implement this but with no success.I would appreciate a simple example to demonstrate how to achieve this because am not too good using the mvc framework as i recently started using ASP.NET.

Comment: You can probably find the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896014/global-variables-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: @ alexbell not what am looking for.thanks anyways

Comment: You are welcome. Also, pertinent to ASP.NET, the standard mechanism of data exchange between pages is to use Cookies or Session Variables. It could be helpful. Best regards,

Comment: You want this value in view or controller ?

Comment: @ mairaj,i want the value in the view,am using the same controller for all my forms.so when the user fills the first form and clicks save,when the user moves next to the other form,the ID number of the user should be passed to the enrollment view so i can save the user enroolment details along with user ID

Answer (score 4):

First lets make it clear this is MVC and not web forms. In MVC the flow goes like this

```
   View ----> Controller----->Model    then back to controller and so on in usual cases.
```

Now what you probably want to do is pass a value(here ID ) from the form in first view to another view, this should probably be done like this.

Say for eg. your textbox storing ID is named "tb1" then write the following code in your controller

```
    int id  = (Request.Form["tb1"]).toString();
    //now we'll store this id in a ViewState varibale like so
    ViewData["id"] = id;
    //don't worry about the data type of ViewData["id"], it would adapt automatically
```

Then after proper redirection, i.e. return of the second view  from your controller, just access this ViewState variable any where you need like so:

```
   @ViewData["id"]
```

Please note that this is Razor syntax and your views need to be in .cshtml pages rather than .aspx pages

Answer (score 0):

You Can use ViewBag.MyProp = "XYZ";
and in our view you can retrieve this as :

var name = "@ViewBag.MyProp"