# Need a global variable in MVC App

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am very new to ASP.Net, Razor and MVC.

How i can declare and access a global variable across all the pages in my MVC application ? Sometimes, this variable will be setting its value from java scripts as well.

I tried with Session and Application objects but no use at all.

Any Help ? I saw other posts here but it seems not suitable.

please help.

Comment: Please rethink if is it needed. If you must use global variables that mean your architecure isn't good enought. For config variable use web.config variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118610/asp-net-mvc-global-variables)

Comment: @Ridikk12 is right use web.config - <add key="ServiceName" value="JackJames" /> and use in controller like - ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"]. Note Returns as string so if int have to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

**For server-side:**
you can read more here: [ASP.NET MVC Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118610/asp-net-mvc-global-variables)

**For javascript:**
If I were you and I would need to implement such a global javascript variable available on many pages, I would use:

a) [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or
b) [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 0):

I know you say that session is "no use at all" but that sounds like your simplest solution.  You can setup a class to handle reading/writing to session and then reference that in all of your controllers and views.

Create a session variables class...or whatever you want to call it.

```
using ...
namespace Application.Data
{
    public static class SessionVariables
    {
        private static object GetValue(string AttrName)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[AttrName];
        }
        private static void SetValue(string AttrName, object AttrValue)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[AttrName] = AttrValue;
        }

        public static int PageIndex
        {
            get => (int?)GetValue("pageIndex") ?? 0;
            set => SetValue("pageIndex", value);
        }
    }
}
```

To reference in your view...

```
@using Application.Data
@{
    var index = SessionVariables.PageIndex;
}
```

This same logic can be used in your controllers.