# Where do I store an object that that needs to be initialized once for a user then needs to be available on all pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an object that contains a connection to an external service. The connection needs to be initialized once when a user logins, otherwise the service will throw an error when the connection is re-initialized.

The connection then needs to be open all the time and should available to multiple controllers that will call the service.

I am using ASP MVC & C#. I am currently initializing the variable when a user session starts and stores it in the user session as well. I am wondering if there are other alternatives to this approach.

Initializing the session variable

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("SomeConnection", new SomeConnection());
}
```

Then I use an extension method that retrieves the connection from the session

```
public static SomeConnection GetSomeConnection(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
{
    return (SomeConnection) HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeConnection"];
}
```

Comment: take a look at this SO post [MVC Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118610/asp-net-mvc-global-variables)

Comment: updated my question with the code

Comment: storing it in a static variable will not work because each connection should be unique for each users, not shared

Comment: when  you put break points in the `Session_Start` method, does it hit that code? also where are you assigning the return value of the `SomeConnection` method value? instead of adding I would expect to see `=` vs adding.. `HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeConnection"] = (SomeConnection) HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeConnection"];`  I would expect to do it this way

Comment: yeah, my current code actually works. I'm only looking for other possible solutions for this if I don't want to store my connection in a session.

Comment: change the static method to either be an Instance method or a protected method

Comment: *"I am wondering if there are other alternatives to this approach."* I'll bet there is at least one alternative, and probably many more. However, that's exactly what the `Session` is for, since the happy days of ASP3 (and probably even before that) - Keeping data scoped to a specific client, as long as that client is still "connected" to the website. You are doing it right.

Comment: cool, good to know. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is:
If you are deploying on load balanced servers, to make this approach work you have to ensure session stickiness.

Otherwise you can use AppFabric to store your object in an independent server and make it available to all your servers. This way you will also be initializing your object only once.

Use `GetExistingOrSet` method.