# ASP.NET MVC - View inheritance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, view, master-pages

This question is a bit related to this one: [How to declare a global variable in ASP.NET MVC page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2974542/866022).

I'm wondering if it is possible to declare and use a variable in a master view (in two separate sectoins), and then, in certain views inheriting this master view, change its value before it is displayed. I haven't gotten to the implementation of this yet, so I can't just test it, but it would be helpful to know how it works before I actually code it so I can do it right the first time.

What I have in mind is something like this.

Master page:

```
<div id="OnePartOfThePage">
Somecontentdisplayedhere
<% string textforlater = "I am a master page"; %>
</div>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" />


<div id="AnotherPartOfThePage">
<%: textforlater %>
<div>
```

And in the inheriting page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
MoreContentHere
<% textforlater = "I am not the master page, I am it's child"; %>
</asp:Content>
```

Is this a workable idea, or should I create and display the string separately in each child?

Comment: why are you creating variables in a view? isn't that what the model is for?

Comment: Excellent point, I should have thought of that. This is the way it has been done in other parts of the application (written by others), and for some reason I just didn't think to do it differently.

Comment: I'll add an answer so we can closed this question off :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the view to store variables, that's what the model is for